Inverse kinematics for pre rigged model in sketchfab titanus scylla
I downloaded this Titanus Scylla model from sketch fab
https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/titanus-scylla-eb99bfcc05bc42ac9477738c4e9b6641
It’s prerigged but when I go into pose mode and I move around a bone it just stretches out. How can I apply inverse kinematics to this model?
Can someone let me know if the bones are connected? What I need to do? Do I need to reorient them? When I go into edit mode the shapes are pointing away from the model
